# Why does my SFDX deployment validation fail while a change set with the same components and specified tests passes?

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, salesforcedx-cli, change-set, mdapideploy

I needed to validate that the deployment of some components would succeed. The deployment would be between two sandboxes of the same production org.

The components were two class/test class pairs that were already in the destination sandbox (i.e. only changes to the existing code were intended for deployment):

```
SetRequestOpportunityFields
SetRequestOpportunityFieldsTest
RemoteTrxPaymentCtrl
RemoteTrxPaymentCtrlTest
```

I wanted to use SFDX to validate. The first step I completed was to convert the items above from source to metadata format (although now it looks like there's no difference for classes).

I ran this command:

```
sfdx force:source:convert -d metadata/10282020INTDEPLOY \
-p force-app/main/default/classes/SetPaymentOpportunityFields.cls,\
force-app/main/default/classes/SetRequestOpportunityFieldsTest.cls,\
force-app/main/default/classes/RemoteTrxPaymentCtrl.cls,\
force-app/main/default/classes/RemoteTrxPaymentCtrlTest.cls
```

That created these files:

[image]

Then I finally ran this command to perform the validation:

```
sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -u hsint -c \
-d metadata/10282020INTDEPLOY \
-l RunSpecifiedTests \
-r SetRequestOpportunityFieldsTest,RemoteTrxPaymentCtrlTest
```

But the validation Failed:

[image]

So I wanted to compare that SFDX validation attempt with a change-set validation.

I created a change set with the same components:

[image]

Then I ran validation on the change set with the same tests specified as my SFDX attempt (and which are the same tests in the deployment package):

[image]

And that validation succeeded:

[image]

So why the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your changeset is different from what you prepared via SFDX.

Your changeset includes `SetRequestOpportunityFields` whereas your sfdx metadata directory includes `SetPaymentOpportunityFields` (for which you have no corresponding test class).

That there is your entire issue.

#### Bonus

You don't need to do the conversion to metadata api form, as force:source:deploy has been able to deploy to sandboxes (and production) for several releases. The following should do what you want

`sfdx force:source:deploy -u hsint -c -m ApexClass:SetRequestOpportunityFields,ApexClass:SetRequestOpportunityFieldsTest,ApexClass:RemoteTrxPaymentCtrl,ApexClass:RemoteTrxPaymentCtrlTest -l RunSpecifiedTests -r SetRequestOpportunityFieldsTest, RemoteTrxPaymentCtrlTest`

the `-m` flag tells sfdx to only use the specified metadata in the deploy operation. Comma-separated list in `<Metadata Type>:<API name>` format.

Comment: That's a great bonus!